# Is this waveform OK for a motor driver?

Tags: mosfet, pwm, dc-motor, motor-controller, mosfet-driver

I made a simple motor driver like this:

[image: motor driver schematic]

The transistor is a 2N2222, the MOSFET is an IRFZ44 and the diode is a 1N4007.

The motor is a 35W 12V one.

I am controlling it with a 1 kHz PWM signal.

I get the following wave measuring with the oscilloscope at the drain (with a duty cycle of 50).

[image: waveform]

Is this okay or do I need to make any changes? Also I'm scared of the 25 V spikes, should I put a Zener to pull them to ground?

Comment: `Also I'm scared of the 25V spikes` Could you please put a picture showing how you are probing? Probing technique is important.

Comment: "measuring with the oscilloscope at the drain", Drain to what? List the used components, specially the freewheeling diode and transistor.

Comment: The oscillogram shows that you are driving the motor in the DCM (Discontinous Conduction Mode), it is generating a pulsating torque. To get it continuous, you have to increase a switching frequency.

Comment: It does not look OK.  show layout and motor specs

Comment: What does voltage on the power supply side of the motor look like?

Comment: And what part number is the diode?

Comment: It is best to use a proper half-bridge as the diode Pd is too great for a motor.  It must be hot.

Comment: Tony Stewart EE75 actually, the diode seems not to be really hot.

Comment: Marko Buršič I suppose that I should lower the value of the resistor at the gate, to increase the frequency? Am I right?

Comment: are you measuring EXACTLY at the drain of the MOSFET (and EXACTLY the source of the mosfet) or are you using some other node which on the circuit is the same, but may have lots of strays?

Comment: JonRB Actually, I'm measuring at the screw therminal, but it is directly connected to the mosfet, there are no other components around.

Comment: What *type* of motor is it?  Some "motors", such as many ventilation fans, actually contain their own driver circuitry.

Comment: rdtsc 12V 35W Brushed motor, I'm pretty sure that it does not contains it's own driver.